# Print web page as PDF and pipe to dataurl

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pdf, printing, data-url

I am working on a project in nodejs and trying to figure out how to do this efficiently.

What I have is an app that has a box to enter a URL and a button. What I want is for the button to store that web page as a dataurl of a PDF. So the long way around would be:
1 enter URL
2 save as PDF
3 convert PDF to dataurl.

I don't want prompts and I don't want to actually save the PDF locally.

The end result I am aiming for would be a dataurl of a website stored in mongo that I could then call upon to view a PDF of that website.

If anyone can help that would be great.

I am learning nodejs so I am welcoming the rtfm, if you could just help me find the manual.

Comment: Without giving it away, you could use phantomjs to render PDF. I maintain phantomjs-node and you could open a page in NodeJS and read it as base64 to store. I wouldn't recommend storing large blobs in Mongo though. It might be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll read the docs and play around with it.